# Run Rest And Socket in Same Server in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, sockets

This is my `app.js` and I want to perform both (Socket/Rest) But When I am emitting something from my client the socket is not connecting though it's showing me 101 Status in chrome ws. Can anyone help me out with what's wrong with this code?

here is my app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
const apiRouter = require("./routes/api");
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
// var memcached = require('memcached');
// var mmc = new memcached('localhost:1121', {retries:10,retry:10000,remove:true});
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());

app.use("/", indexRouter); 
app.use("/api", apiRouter);  
require("./app/router/login.router")(app);
require("./app/router/match.router")(app);
require("./app/router/competetion.router")(app);

server.listen(port,() => {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port
  console.log(`Admin listening on port ${port}!`);
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('12---------12');
  socket.on("test" , (data) => {
    console.log('test', data);
  })
});

// -- @ socket manual --


// -- @ socket ends ---
```

When I am emitting something its showing 101 status but nothing emitting at all

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when considering the only problem is connecting to socket io, your code should establish a bi directional connection between the client and the server, and it does.

The 101 message means `switching protocols`

so if you emit a message on event named `test` your server will catch it.

the problem is in your client side, try any ready to use tools like [this](https://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool) or anything else to independently test your socket io server

Comment: i test with this tool and its connecting. Now I have a clear vision where to go ! thanks